# Lumen server not responding after a while

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, lumen, hhvm

I have a PHP web server powered by Nginx,HHVM and Lumen, when I start the server using this command : `php artisan serv --port="8081" --host"x.x.x.x"`
it will start and running perfectly for a while like two weeks max! 
then it will die and not responding anything! It's not on heavy load of requests. I don't know if it's HHVM related issues or Lumen problem?!

Comment: it is `serve` not `serv`

Comment: Check acquired port or try with other port

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: `php artisan serve` is for development only, don't expect to behave a like a webserver which works without issues for long time. So either setup a proper server. Or use systemd to or some another process manager to keep the process running

Comment: @TarunLalwani what command do you suggest to start the app in production mode?

Comment: Prod should use a apache to serve the app or use Nginx+PHP-FPM combination

Comment: well it has fpm running on Nginx, also I run the command using nohup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan serve` is the development way of things. when you start your affirmation and say that you have a NGINX server and then say that you are using the dev server build in Laravel it's way to wrong. You need to configure NGINX to serve the Lumen app with it ([example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) of linux server, nginx and lumen). I hope the example will clear your vision on this situation.